# Layout inspector not showing compose nodes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, layout-inspector

Trying to inspect my pure Compose app in the layout inspector shows the screen without any layout node information. No errors in the logs. This happens on both real devices and emulators. I have tried Android Studio Bumblebee (latest patch) and Chipmunk (Beta). Compose version is 1.1.1

[image: Layout inspector]

Comment: I run into this issue often, where sometimes the layout inspector works with compose but then it stops working. For some reason I am able to get it back to working by enabling "Disable adb authorization timeout", revoking usb debugging authorization and toggling usb debugging.

Comment: I also found out that if you select a compose view on the inspector preview, it will show the compose tree even though it originally did not show the compose nodes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When only the views are shown, but no Composables, make sure to **not** exclude `.version` files from `META-INF`, since the compose UI tooling utilizes them, e.g. **remove/adjust** these:

```
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += "META-INF/*.version"
    }
}
```

or

```
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += "META-INF/**"
    }
}
```

Comment: Android Studio - Flamingo, Add "excludes += "META-INF/**", Layout inspctor also not show compose and tip "Compose inspection unavailable. Could not determine the version of the androidx.compose.ui:ui artifact. Was the version file excluded?"

Comment: @dipdipdip What is "META-INF"? Sorry have never heard of what this is. I looked in my project in Android Studio, using a few different hierarchy/project view types, and didn't see anything.