# Android Studio Layout Inspector cannot display compose nodes - "try restarting the application"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, layout-inspector

What the title says. I have tried restarting the app and the studio, invalidated caches, etc. All I get is the message in a blue banner that says `"Cannot display compose nodes - try restarting the application"`.

I have already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73700099/949280) and commented out everything in the `packagingOptions` section in the build.gradle file.

I'm using Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1. Appreciate any pointers or suggestions!